# How to configure test file xml in sonarqube?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I use sonarqube for JS Project, I would like to integrate the XML result for the unit test. I have this error :

```
ERROR: Caused by: Line 2 of report refers to a file which is not configured as a test file: modules/project/projectTest.js
```

I don't understand why this error is here. 
The projectTest file get analysed, do I need to set something so that sonarqube can handle them as test files.

My XML result file :

```
<testExecutions version="1">
 <file path="modules/proejct/projectTest.js">
  <testCase name="Test" duration="16"/>
 </file>
</testExecutions>
```

Thank you for your hlep

Answer (score 0):

Files referenced in your unit test report need to be test files, in other words they should be configured by sonar.tests property. See docs https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters